Humidistat and wall switch combo bathroom exhaust fan
Can I have a humidistat and separate wall switch on a bathroom exhaust fan? I want the automatic fan when the kids forget and the switch for a fart fan.

A typical separate humidistat (as opposed to one integrated with the fan unit), such as this Leviton from Home Depot:

includes automatic turn-on/off by sensing high humidity and allows you to press a button to manually turn on the fan when desired.
Fans that include a humidity sensor can work a few different ways:

Include a switch with humidity sensor like the Leviton shown above
Include a humidity sensor in the fan enclosure and make use of a regular power switch which would normally be "on" so that the humidity sensor can work but allow a toggle of the power switch to trigger a timed manual run of the fan.
Use an extra pair of wires to connect a non-powered switch for manual fan control.

